# Write and Read Tuple of Bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

Im using following python library to connect with a fingerprint scanner

https://github.com/gtors/fprint

It requires scanned fingerprint data instances to stored in tuples to verify against multiple fingers. The example given in library only supports enrolling and verifying against single finger.

How can I write `PrintData` as tuples to a file after `enroll_finger_loop` function and load them again for `identify_finger` function

```
import fprint
fprint.init()
 
ddevs = fprint.DiscoveredDevices()
if len(ddevs) > 0:
    dev = ddevs[0].open_device()
    print_data = dev.enroll_finger_loop()
 
    if print_data is None:
        print("Fail")
    else:
        print("Success")
 
        fingerprints = (print_data,)
    #in here i need to write fingerprints to a file and load them back in to matched
    matched = dev.identify_finger(fingerprints)
 
    if matched:
        print("Match!")
    else:
        print("Not a Match")
 
    dev.close()
 
fprint.exit()
```

In simple, I want to know how to write tuple of bytes to a file and read them back later. I'm fairly new to Python.

Thanks

Comment: What did you try to store tuples? what was your probelm? Did you research about storing data into files? What did you find? What did you not understand when trying to do it with your data? Did you stumble over pickling? Storing as string representation and ast.literal_evaling it?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Please check this : https://pastebin.com/j6jjgMSL

Comment: Pickling gives the error : self.ptr cannot be converted to a Python object for pickling

Answer (score 0):

You can store a tuple of tuple per line in a file and use `ast.literal_eval` to parse it back into tuples:

```
prints = [ ((42,48,49),(76,99,101)),  # fingerprint 1
           ((11,22,33),(44,55,66))]   # fingerprint 2 etc

# store in file, one print per line
with open("file.txt","w") as f: 
    for p in prints:
        f.write(str(p) + "\n")

# read from file, one print per line
from ast import literal_eval

# store read prints
print_list = [] 
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line: 
            # parse as tuple and add to list
            print_list.append( literal_eval(line) )

print(d)
```

Output:

```
[((42, 48, 49), (76, 99, 101)), ((11, 22, 33), (44, 55, 66))]
```

---

You might need to store as binary ([see here](https://github.com/gtors/fprint/blob/master/examples/enroll.py)):

```
# Persist fingerprint info
with open("some_fingerprint", "wb") as fh:
    fh.write(print_data.data)

# Load fingerprint info from a binary file (see enroll.py)
with open('some_fingerprint', 'rb') as fh:
    fingerprint = fprint.PrintData.from_data(fh.read())
```

If you want to store multiple, store multiple files.

Comment: Writing works fine, this is written in file.txt : <fprint.PrintData object at 0x766baf10>
(I think converting to string is not the way)

And Reading from file.txt throws error : https://pastebin.com/Xuc4eb0q